# Refreshing specific DIV

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a ticketing system, sometimes the ticket content is too long and I want to display only part of it (first 172 characters) - which I did with no real issues, to view the full content (at the same page) I'm creating `href` for toggeling text (show more/less) and along with it I want to display the full content or just part of it.

But I can't find a way to do it.
Right now when I pull the data of the ticket I'm displaying it like this:

`{ticket.content.length !==0? <div id='content' className='meta-data'>{ticket.content.substr(0, this.state.short_content)}</div> : null}`

Following it with:

`<div id='showing' onClick={this.showMore} className={ticket.id}>Show More</div>`

The function:

```
showMore = () => {
        var txt_swapper = document.getElementById("showing");
        var full_txt = document.getElementById("content");
        var full_content = full_txt!.innerHTML;
        if (txt_swapper!.innerHTML === "Show More") {
            txt_swapper!.innerHTML = "Show Less";
            this.state.short_content=999;
            full_txt!.innerHTML=full_content;
        } else {
            txt_swapper!.innerHTML = "Show More";
            this.state.short_content=172;
        }
    }
```

I tried follow some guides here but all sent to to JQuery and I don't think I need to use it.
How can I refresh a specific DIV (or to be more precise my 'content' DIV) using either javascript typescript or HTML?

Comment: you need to update `state` by calling `this.setState({ short_content: value })`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the state using `this.setState`.

```js
showMore = () => {
  var txt_swapper = document.getElementById("showing");
  var full_txt = document.getElementById("content");
  var full_content = full_txt!.innerHTML;
  if (txt_swapper!.innerHTML === "Show More") {
    txt_swapper!.innerHTML = "Show Less";
    this.setState({
      short_content: 999
    })
    full_txt!.innerHTML = full_content;
  } else {
    txt_swapper!.innerHTML = "Show More";
    this.setState({
      short_content: 172
    })
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: As said earlier, that resolved my issue, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do DOM manipulation in React. This is almost *never* the right way to do things.

Just toggle a state variable based on whether or not you want to be showing the full ticket or not, then render based on that state.

In React, you shouldn't be doing direct manipulation of the DOM; instead, you manipulate your data, and your component *reacts* to those data changes.

```
function Ticket({ content, truncateLength }) {
  const [showFull, setShowFull] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleText = showFull ? "Show Less" : "Show More";

  const visibleContent = showFull ? content : content.substr(0, truncateLength);

  return (
    <div ticket>
      <p>{visibleContent}</p>
      <span
        style={{ textDecoration: "underline", cursor: "pointer" }}
        onClick={() => setShowFull(!showFull)}
      >
        {toggleText}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here's a sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-tree-6xypv) for you to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

As Thinker suggested (comment to original post), I should've changed:
`this.state.short_content=999;` to: `this.setState({short_content:999});`

Answer (score 0):

```
const fullContent = 'your full content'; //Your original content
let displayContent = ''; //What you will show on the screen at a time

var showMore = false; //Are you showing right now or not

showMoreElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
if(!showMore) {
  showMore = true;
  displayContent = fullContent;
  showMoreElement.textContent = 'Show Less';
} else {
  showMore = false;
  displayContent = 'first 172 char of your content';
  showMoreElement.textContent = 'Show More';
}
});
```

Here is what happens here:

First you have your original content. Then you create a variable that holds 172 char of your content or your full content depending on the showMore variable that decides if person clicked the Show More link or not. And you control that with an event listener on your Show More button. Hope it helps.